# Ctree Specializer is using for loop index for computation, not the actual array value

Tags: python, c, code-generation

I'm implementing a simple Xor Reducer, but it is unable to return the appropriate value.

Python Code (Input):

```
class LazySpecializedFunctionSubclass(LazySpecializedFunction):

    subconfig_type = namedtuple('subconfig',['dtype','ndim','shape','size','flags'])

    def __init__(self, py_ast = None):
        py_ast = py_ast or get_ast(self.kernel)
        super(LazySlimmy, self).__init__(py_ast)

    # [... other code ...]

    def points(self, inpt):
        iter = np.nditer(input, flags=['c_index'])
        while not iter.finished:
            yield iter.index
            iter.iternext()


class XorReduction(LazySpecializedFunctionSubclass):
    def kernel(self, inpt):
        '''
            Calculates the cumulative XOR of elements in inpt, equivalent to
            Reduce with XOR
        '''
        result = 0
        for point in self.points(inpt):  # self.points is defined in LazySpecializedFunctionSubclass
            result = point ^ result      # notice how 'point' here is the actual element in self.points(inpt), not the index
        return result
```

C Code (Output):

```
// <file: module.c>
void kernel(long* inpt, long* output) {
    long result = 0;
    for (int point = 0; point < 2; point ++) {
         result = point ^ result;   // Notice how it's using the index, point, not inpt[point]. 
    };
    * output = result;
};
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using point in different ways, in XorReduction kernel method you are iterating of the values in the array, but in the generated C code you are iterating over the indices of the array.  Your C code xor reduction is thus done on the indices.
The generated C function should look more like

```
// <file: module.c>
void kernel(long* inpt, long* output) {
    long result = 0;
    for (int point = 0; point < 2; point ++) {
         result = inpt[point] ^ result;  // you did not reference your input in the question
    };
    * output = result;
};
```